# Is there a way of arranging symbols in *lattice::segploplot* pch keeping specific order in R?

Tags: r

Hy guys,
I'm trying to arrange symbols of my *lattice::segploplot* in same order as sample size legends. No success until now? Does anyone knows how to help me?

Header of the image bellow has sample sizes where 50 leads to a circle, 100 leads to a triangle and so on... I need to arrange geometric forms over each line in the same sequence of sample size legends for each beta from small to big lines, but always the geometric forms for each line appears in random order. Note: big lines comes from small samples sizes and sort lines comes from bigger sample sizes. I'm using lattice, but any help in ggplot2 are welcome!

[image]

[Those are the code of my attempts and a Sample Data for Testing](https://www.dropbox.com/s/azzda84oomoy6a4/data_sample_segplot.csv?dl=0)

```
require(lattice)
require(latticeExtra)
require(tidyverse)

ac <- list(pad1=0.5, pad2=0.5, tck=0.5)
mycol <- gray. Colors(n=5)
pch_values <- c(1, 2, 22, 19, 17)

ps <- list(box.rectangle=list(col=1, fill=c("gray70")),
           box.umbrella=list(col=1, lty=1),
           dot.symbol=list(col=1),
           dot. Line=list(col=1, lty=3),
           plot.symbol=list(col=1, cex=0.7),
           plot. Line=list(col=1),
           plot.polygon=list(col="gray80"),
           superpose.line=list(col=mycol),
           superpose.symbol=list(col=mycol),
           superpose.polygon=list(col=mycol),
           strip.background=list(col=c("gray90","gray65")),
           layout.widths=list(
             left.padding=0.25,
             right.padding=-1,
             ylab.axis.padding=0),
           layout.heights=list(
             bottom.padding=0.25,
             top.padding=0,
             axis.xlab.padding=0,
             xlab.top=0),
           axis.components=list(bottom=ac, top=ac, left=ac, right=ac)
)

panel.segplotBy <- function(x, y, z, centers, subscripts, groups, pch, f, ...){
  d <- 2*((as.numeric(groups)-1)/(nlevels(groups)-1))-1
  z <- as.numeric(z)+f*d
  panel.segplot(x, y, z, centers=centers,
                subscripts=subscripts, pch = pch, ...)
}

fn_plot_beta_bias <- function(data, .type = "m", titulo = "Sample Size"){
  da <- data      
  # Legend
  key <- list(text = list(levels(da$n)),
              title = titulo,
              cex.title = 1.0,
              lines = list(pch = unique(da$pch_col)), 
              divide = c(1), columns = 5, type="o")
  
  # Labels
  la <- expression(phi=="5", phi=="10", phi=="25", phi=="50", phi=="100")
  lb <- c(expression(beta[0], beta[1], beta[2]))
  lc <- expression(NRS[11], NRS[21])
  
  # Figure 1
  p1 <- segplot(coefs ~ bias_ci_lower + bias_ci_upper | phi + ncuts,
                centers = bias, 
                data = da, 
                group = n,
                xlim = c(-0.25, 0.25),
                par.settings = ps, 
                f = 0.3, 
                panel = panel.segplotBy, 
                layout = c(NA,1),
                horizontal = TRUE, 
                par.strip.text = list(cex = 1.1),
                strip = strip.custom(factor. Levels = la),
                scales = list(y = list(at = 1:3, labels = c(lb), cex = 0.92)),
                pch = pch_values,
                cex = 0.8, key = key,
                xlab = expression(hat(bias) %+-% SD))
  
  p1 <- p1 + latticeExtra::layer(panel.abline(v = 0, lty = 2))
  p1 <- latticeExtra::useOuterStrips(x = p1, 
                                     strip = strip.custom(var.name = da$phi,
                                                          factor.levels = la),
                                     strip. Left = strip.custom(var.name = da$ncuts,
                                                               factor.levels = lc))
  return(p1)
  
}
```

Thanks for any help!